# Missing field name comment in creating form on sharepoint designer

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-addin, list-form, aspx

Seems like i don't see a comment when i tried to create a copy of my NewForm.aspx in SharePoint Designer. How would i fix this one?

This image below is the source code of NewForm.aspx
[image]

This one is for the NewFormCopy.aspx

[image]

I need to have the comment part i guess, in order to use SPutility on Codeplex

Need help. Thanks

Comment: Need help for this